# Selecting last column of a Numpy array while maintaining then umber of dimensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

If `a` is a multi-dimensional array, `a[..., j]` gives an array of shape `a.shape[:-1]`.  So, for example if `a` is a `m`-by-`n` matrix `a[..., j]` gives an `m` dimensional vector of shape `(m,)`.  What is the correct way to do the above-mentioned slicing such that the result has the same number of dimensions as `a` with the last dimension having size `1`.  For example `a[<magical_slice>]` for the `m`-by-`n` array should give a (column) vector of shape `(m, 1)`.

Currently I am using

```
a[..., j].rehape(a.shape[:-1] + (1,))
```

To achieve that goal.  However, that looks too complicated (and most probably inefficient) for what I would like to do.

Comment: A tiny example of matrix with desired output would be much appreciated :)

Comment: `a[..., [j]]` or `a[..., j:j+1]`.